# Is there a way to prevent Custom Event triggers to override previous virtual page view?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a single page application in which we set Google Tag Manager.
We have multiple event triggered by different means (click on a tooltip button, for example) and we send events to the dataLayer when we "change" page. Then we use this event to trigger a Page View in Google Tag Manager.

Whenever we look at real time (and not real time) data, we see the active page changing as we navigate the app. However, let's say I'm on the `/home` page, and I click on a tooltip button : the active page is reset to `/`, and every data for the /home (like time on page, or exits) are therefore false.

We could have add to every single event the page it is on, but it poses 2 problems :

1. It would trigger the same page view multiple times, not helping with the time stats and other
2. Some events are spread on all virtual pages; like the tooltips

I tried SETTING the page with ga, and removing other page view triggers from GTM

```
ga('set', 'page', 'home');
ga('set', 'title', 'Home page');
ga("send", "pageview");
```

But when I click anything that triggers an event, the page still goes to `/`.

What I would like is to

1. Trigger a virtual page view on a precise event OR by sending it directly to GA
2. Maintaining this page view as the active page until I get to an event that triggers the next page
3. Not altering the page with any other custom event

Comment: Can you share your SPA?

Comment: @zborovskaya no, unfortunately I can't share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, URL doesn't change and you write URLs for virtual pages manually in Page View tag in GTM. But events by default use URL of real page - '/'. And you want events to be related to the active (virtual) page.

Don't mix GTM and hardcoded events for GA in this way: pageview in GTM, events in code. It doesn't work.

Add `virtualPageUrl` and `virtualPageTitle`to your events to the dataLayer when page changes like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var dataLayer=dataLayer||[];
   dataLayer.push({
      'event':'VirtualPageview',
      'virtualPageURL':'/lalala/',
      'virtualPageTitle':'Home'
});
</script>
```

Create dataLayer variables `virtualPageUrl` and `virtualPageTitle` in GTM:

[image]

Use these variables in your events/pageviews in GTM:

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! The key of your answer was really this sentence : `Don't mix GTM and hardcoded events for GA in this way: pageview in GTM, events in code. It doesn't work.`

There was a problem I didn't expose in my question, since I didn't know it was one : 
I always sent every dataLayerVariables, even when they weren't modified by my code, so I sent, in each event, `null`. I am now no longer sending the url and title if my event is not intended to change the PageView !

Thanks a lot !